# Unable to delete node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, delete-file

I am trying to delete the node modules folder from my project so that I can rerun `npm i` as there were errors when I was running my npm scripts (I think node_modules corrupted), but I don't seem to be able to.

I've tried:

- Deleting via right clicking in Windows explorer. This just doesn't do anything.
- In VS Code right clicking and selecting 'Delete Node Modules', which produces the following message: [image]

I think the node modules file has corrupted - there only seems to be 3 folders in there, all of which I can't delete.
[image]

If I run `npm i` I get the following:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried closing VS Code or any other apps in which node modules folder is open and then delete it from file explorer or command line.

Comment: Yes - still doesn't delete

Comment: This seems more like a Windows question than a Node.js question

Answer (score 1):

Try to reboot windows with **SAFE MOOD**.
I face the same issue on windows 10. I could delete it when I have been in a safe mood on windows.

Don't know really an issue on windows or my hard drive.